# Really Weird Font-Rendering Issue on Android Browser

Tags: android, html, css, fonts, rendering

I've got really weird Font-Rendering Problems with my Galaxy Nexus Phone, Android Version 4.3.

It changes the font on some lines, but I have no idea why. There is no tag between them, it's all written in a plain `<p>` tag or heading-tag.

What could be the source of the problem?

I've tried other fonts, but it happens to all of them. Georgia, Arial, Helvetica...

Picture:

[image]

Comment: Without seeing the html it is difficult. Look at the page on a desktop browser and check the styles (using F12) are applied there. There is a known error when part of of font has not downloaded it will show only the glyphs it has downloaded ... as it is only the items with umlauts that are failing on your pages ... have you checked that the umlauted glyphs exist in the web font you are using?

Comment: That's the problem. It looks okay on all other Browsers. It's just this one Android Browser on this particular mobile phone.
It looks great on my iphone or galaxy nexus 4.

Comment: is your content inside a table? if the answer is yes it looks like the default table style is overriding your style in some parts

Comment: Then do a test - is it the umlaut that triggers the issue. I notised that the ß line rendered fine ... good luck.

Comment: no it's not in a table.

Answer (score 2):

The umlauts were actually causing this weird behaviour.

Comment: Be interested in hearing how you fixed ... was it a codepage you needed to add, or maybe use a different glyph for umlauts (are there multiple for the same visual style) or was it due to the code editor or copy and paste?

Comment: Are you doing a head-slap in your avatar photo ;)